# Retrieving a user's ID when trying to add a friend with Django

Tags: python, html, django

Okay so I'm making a friend system for a website, it's going pretty well. I've been able to create a relationship between two users (friendship) when I manually enter the proper URL. However that's the problem, I need to manually enter it, here's my urls.py:

```
   url(r'^profile_test/connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.change_friends, name='change_friends')
```

Here's the views.py:

```
def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    #this view will manage a user's friends
    other_user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.objects.add_friend(
            request.user, other_user, message='Hi, I would like to add you')

    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.objects.remove_friend(request.user, other_user)


    return HttpResponse(Friend.objects.friends(request.user))
```

As you can see the view takes the arguments `operation` and `pk`, the operation will be adding or removing a friend and the pk will be the primary key of the user that you want to add as a friend.

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically generate the ID of the user that is being added, so I can put it in a URL. So this HTML code would need to do it but I don't know how:

`<a href='http://localhost:8000/profile_test/connect/add/dynamically-generated-pk/'> Click </a>`

How should I go about this? I'm using the `django-friendship` package btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `render` your html, you will want to pass a list `pk_list` of the dynamically-generated-pk you want to be able to store as links on the page. I'm not sure which users you want available to put in your link, but if its all users, you can do something like:

**views.py**

```
pk_list = [obj.pk for obj in User.objects.all()] #TBD: remove the current user
render(request, 'example.html', {'pk_list': pk_list})
```

**example.html**

```
{% for pk in pk_list %}
    <a href='http://localhost:8000/profile_test/connect/add/{{pk}}'> Click </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll try this when I get home. I was just about to confirm how to make the list and then you edited it. You're a mind reader

Comment: @Amon I haven't tested it, so let my know if you run into any issues!

Comment: @Amon You'll probably also want to remove yourself from the pk_list, you will have to figure out how to get the current users pk.

Comment: That sounds simple enough but why is it required? So you can't add yourself?

Comment: I just want to put the pk of the user's whose profile I am on

Comment: @Amon its not required, I'm just pointing it out since It probably wouldn't make sense to add yourself. If you plan on having a separate page for each user, then instead of a list, you would just pass the pk of the user whose page you are viewing.

Comment: I'm having an issue with passing `pk_list` as a context, I can't do it because you can't pass lists in a dictionary. So I think I need to convert it to a tuple

Comment: Fixed the problem, I need to use django syntax to pass info to the view `<a href="{% url 'change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}"> Click </a>` instead of just giving it the URL. So right now it seems I don't even need to make a separate list and pass the context